# Будет ли равномерным распределение заданий в очереди?

Tags: python, многопоточность, очередь

Нужно что-то вроде RR.

Будет ли равномерным распределение заданий в очереди `Queue.Queue()` по тредам? Смущает то что задания появляться будут медленней чем выполнение команд по ним.

Запускаю несколько тредов (с разным кодом под разные устройства) и тред который принимает задания по http. Задание попадает в очередь, а до  этого воркеры висят заблокированном queue.get().

Я использовал в другом проекте `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` - там все красиво и равномерно, но сейчас треды имеют разный код внутри и одной функцией не обойдешься.

Задача разгрузить исполнительные устройсва, а не процессор.

Comment: 1- `threading.pool` не существует. Возможно вы имели ввиду `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`. 2- Можно *разные* функции вызвать, используя ThreadPool—нет нужды его переизобретать. 3- В любом случае: какая разница какой поток работу выполняет? Если вы пытаетесь "равномерностью" распределения улучшить какую-то характеристику, то спросите прямо об этой характеристике.

Comment: 1-да, я скорее о multiprocessing.dummy.Pool . 2- задача разгрузить исполнительные устройства

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сперва почему-то хотелось ответить, что распределение неравномерное - то есть часть потоков будет простаивать, а тот, что был создан первее всех будет отдуваться за всех. Видимо такой поспешный вывод из-за наивного представления потоков в воображении. Но вот эксперимент (py3) - задания появляются в два раза медленнее, чем обрабатываются:

```
import queue
import threading
import time
import random

counter = {}
lock = threading.Lock()

def worker():
    while True:
        try:
            sleep = q.get()
            if sleep == "DIE":
                q.task_done()
                return
            print(threading.current_thread().name)
            with lock:
                counter[threading.current_thread().name] = counter.get(threading.current_thread().name, 0) + 1
            time.sleep(sleep)
            q.task_done()
        except queue.Empty:
            pass


q = queue.Queue()
pool = [threading.Thread(target=worker, name="Worker " + str(i)) for i in range(4)]
[t.start() for t in pool]
for i in range(100):
    rand_sleep = random.random() / 8
    q.put(rand_sleep)
    time.sleep(rand_sleep * 2)
for i in range(4):
    q.put("DIE")

q.join()

print("Report: ", counter)
```

Вот что скрипт выводит:

```
output: ('Report: ', {'Worker 2': 25, 'Worker 3': 25, 'Worker 0': 25, 'Worker 1': 25})
```

Как видно из результатов - для моего кода распределение равномерное.

Если задания поступают без задержек - то распределение неравномерное и зависит от того, как долго обрабатывает задание каждый поток.

Дополнение: данный скрипт был протестирован в Windows и Ubuntu, использовался Python3.4 и Python2.7. Во всех четырех случаях результаты одинаковы.

Comment: Что "равномерность" здесь даёт? Допустим всю работу выполнял бы только один поток здесь—какие негативные последствия вы видите? Учитывая, что ввод поступает медленнее чем обрабатывается—не ясно зачем вообще больше одного потока иметь в этом случае.

Comment: а если саму "работу" выполняет не компьютер? пример - распределить заявки между людьми (чтоб их зарплата была равномерна). еще пример отправлять смски с нескольких модемов (у каждого по 300 смс в абонентской плате)

Comment: @jfs, равномерность ничего не дает. Если точно известно, что задания поступают медленнее, чем обрабатываются (например, раз в секунду с датчика какого-нибудь и результат нужно поместить в БД), то можно и без дополнительных потоков обойтись, упростив код. С одним потоком негативные последствия - можно натянуть потерю масштабируемости - завтра подключат сто новых датчиков и без async один поток не успеет все обработать - пока он будет ожидать ответа от БД, придет новая информация и так накапливаясь, пока памяти хватает.

Comment: @eri, если работу выполняет не компьютер, то тогда вообще непонятно при чем тут питоновские потоки. Для моделирования условного 'распределения заявок в бухгалтерии' есть Теория Массового Обслуживания (Queueing theory) с помощью которой очень легко и быстро можно смоделировать любую подобную ситуацию. Есть даже специальные языки программирования (GPSS) для этого. Правда я никогда не видел, чтобы кто-нибудь этим всерьез занимался.

Comment: а кто задания раздаст?)